# Оператор exists Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Cтолкнулся с проблемой, что вывод после запуска запроса:

```
SELECT "ID_Покупателя" FROM Покупка WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Покупка WHERE "ID_Продавца" = 1);
```

В задании сказано, что нужно вывести ID_Покупателя, который совершал покупки у продавца с id = 1 (с использованием EXISTS).

в результате моего запроса выводятся абсолютно все записи таблицы из столбца "ID_Покупателя".

Таблица будет представлена на скрине.

Может кто объяснить что не так ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: exists дает истину когда внутренний подзапрос возвращает хотя бы одну строку. Но указанный вами внутри запрос всегда возвращает одну и ту же строку по id-продавца, вне зависимости от того, какая строка проверяется снаружи. вам надо в where подзапроса указать некое условие по которому внутреняя таблица соединяется с внешней

Comment: Судя по заданию видимо внешний запрос вообще должен делать выборку из некоей таблицы покупателей, которая в вашем вопросе вообще не фигурирует, а exists должен искать записи с продавцом 1 и покупателем из внешней части запроса в таблице покупок.

Comment: @Mike я добавил скрины таблиц, я просто хотел упростить поставленный запрос. а вообще в задании говориться, найти покупателей, которые делали покупки в магазинах "Наука" и "Знание"

Comment: @Mike да, спасибо. я вот так сделал `select "id" from Покупатель where exists (select * from Покупка п where п."ID_Покупателя" = Покупатель."id" and п."ID_Продавца" = 1);`

Comment: @Andrew предлагаю добавить distinct в основной запрос, что бы id покупателей не дублировались